# No parallel, how many vectors to add in order to return to the starting point of the first vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assuming that none of the vectors are parallel, how many vectors would you need to add together in order to return to the starting point of the first vector?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please [include your work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) – have you tried drawing a diagram of what one vector or two vectors would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count zero vector, then the answer is $1$. If zero vector is excluded, the answer is $3$. You add a non-zero vector and undo it by adding its negative. Since the negative can't be directly added, it is obtained as the resultant of two vectors. You can visualize it as a triangle with the starting point as one of its vertices.

Comment: Good answer, but please do not answer questions where the OP has not shown any effort.

Comment: Could you tell me what would be the equation of those 3 ?

Comment: @Maro As an example, let the starting point be $(0,0)$, and the three vectors $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,-1)$ describe the three successive displacements. No two displacements are collinear, but they add up to $0$.

Comment: would it be like adding (1,0) and (-1,0) to each other as one of them?

Comment: @Maro Yes, because $(1,0)+[(0,1)+(-1,-1)]=(1,0)+(-1,0)$. Note that $(-1,0)$ couldn't be directly added because it's parallel to $(1,0)$.

Comment: oh that makes sense thanks